# Return word before a matched word using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to extract and print the word that occurs just before a specific word I am matching.
As an example,

```
There are 12 processes running.
```

Here I am using sed to search for the word `processes` and I would just like to print `12`.

Is this possible using `sed`?

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to handle that one line, you could use the sed command

```
sed -e 's/.* \([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\) processes running\./\1/'
```

For a slightly more robust approach, the following script will accept arbitrary input and only respond if something matched

```
sed -ne 's/.* \([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\) processes running\./\1/p'
```

Comment: @wrym, this does not work for me.
sed: Function s/.* ([[:digit:]]+) processes running\./\1/ cannot be parsed.

Does this mean that sed is expecting it to be a number? This doesn't need to be the case always, does it.

Comment: Look in the edit history for my answer and try the version I initially posted. Also, what version of sed are you using?

Comment: Actually, try this version. This one should be fully POSIX compliant.

Comment: Thanks, the above works if it is a number in front of the word "processes". It does not work if the sentence is: There are no processes running.

Comment: Okay, then, 0 is a special case. Is 1 also a special case? Does your source display "There is 1 process running." instead of "There are 1 processes running." ?

Comment: No, only 0 seems to be the special case.

Comment: You can replace the [:digit:] character class with [:alnum:] or [:graph:] to match letters, also.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand, you just need to find any word (in common case) and print word before.

Solution in `GNU sed`:

```
sed -rn 's/(^|(.* ))([^ ]*) YOUR_WORD(( .*)|$)/\3/; T; p; q'
```

#### Explanation

`-r` is extended GNU regexp;

`-n` is command to do not print;

`(^|(.* ))` — prefix before word what you want to print. It can be start of line (`^`) or (`|`) space-ended characters (`(.* )`);

`([^ ])*)` — word that will be printed (`\3`);

`YOUR_WORD` — replace it to word, after word you find. (Like «running» after «process»);

`(( .*)|$)` — end of line after words, end (`$`) or space and some characters;

`\3` is found word;

`T` is «jump to end if substitution hasn't done successfully», GNU extension. It will jump to end of script for each line, that doesn't contain `YOUR_WORD` as non-first word;

`p` is «print buffer», print found word (if `T` didn't work in this line);

`q` is command for stopping `sed` execution, 'cos we have already found word (didn't jump with `T`) and we don't need to find new words.

#### Update: solution without GNU extensions

```
sed -n 's/\(^\|\(.* \)\)\([^ ]*\) YOUR_WORD\(\( .*\)\|$\)/\3/; tprint; b; :print; p; q
```

Explanation is the same, difference in backslashes and `t`. `t` works as `T`, but jumps if substitution **was** successful. If it's so, we jump to «print and quit», if not — `b` sends as to and of script and next line processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. However, the -r option does not work for me as I do not have GNU sed installed in RHEL.

Comment: Ok, i'll rewrite it after few time to drop dependency from GNU sed.

Comment: I've done, you can try to use it now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a complicated `sed` substitution, you could just use a fixed-string `grep` search and `cut`:

```
$ grep -F 'processes' file | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

Comment: Doesn't answer "_print the word that occurs just before a specific word I am matching_"

Comment: @roaima It does, given the example that he presents. It matches the specific word "processes" and prints the word that occurs before it.  If he has more complicated data or not, we don't know.

Comment: Consider `We have now got 14 processes running`. The OP is matching on `processes` so by the written requirement that should return `14`, but your code would return `now`.

Comment: @roaima Yes it would return `14`. Consider `There are 13\nprocesses running` (two lines). That would break a `sed` solution too. We simply don't know what his data looks like, apart from the bit he presented.

Comment: @roaima Sorry, in my previous comment I meant to say "Yes, it would return `now`"! Too late to edit...